# SQL Server 2012 Filtered Index - Is the Where clause too complex

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to create the following filtered index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [MyIndex] ON [dbo].[MyTable]
(
    [MovedToODS] ASC
)
INCLUDE 
(   
    [sub_id],
    [read_time]
) 
WHERE ([read_time]>='1/1/2012' OR [LastModifiedTime] > [MovedToODS])
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OR'.

Is a `Where` clause like this not supported for filtered indexes? The online docs simply say the `Where` clause supports 'simple operations'. Is this too complex?

Comment: The grammar is in the answer to your question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/7675546/73226 . No `OR` allowed.

Comment: If you think about it, how would the optimizer be able to take advantage of something like that?  The where clause of your query pretty much needs to match the where clause of your filtered index.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server - Creating Filtered Indexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675514/sql-server-creating-filtered-indexes)

Comment: Also there is [a Connect item asking for OR support](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/666238)

Comment: @Andrew I'm guessing that's the date they moved everything over to ODS!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, your `WHERE` clause is too complex; I don't believe `OR` is supported at all. You can't even do this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.floob(id INT);

CREATE INDEX x ON dbo.floob(id) WHERE id = 1 OR id = 2;
```

In this case of course there is a supported alternative:

```
CREATE INDEX x ON dbo.floob(id) WHERE id IN (1,2);
```

That doesn't really help you. What you could do, though, is create two independent filtered indexes, if it makes sense for your workload to use them independently. Example:

```
WHERE [read_time]>='20120101' AND [LastModifiedTime] <= [MovedToODS]
...
WHERE [read_time]<'20120101' AND [LastModifiedTime] > [MovedToODS]
```

Some decent references that talk about the various limitations:

http://sqlfool.com/2009/04/filtered-indexes-what-you-need-to-know/

http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/11/what-you-can-and-cant-do-with-filtered-indexes/

http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/04/t-sql-queries/filtered-indexes

Comment: any updates to these limitations in recent years? the OR limitation still seems to be there :-(

Comment: @Simon_Weaver No.